# modal not working in big screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

the modal is showing up for small screen....
but the modal is not showing up for bigger screen....
how to fix the issue....
providing my code and fiddle below

working:
http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/KNPZB/6/

not working:

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/KNPZB/6/embedded/result/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#myModal').modal({ show: false })
    </script>


<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >&times;</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only remove the line 5614 of the css

From:

```
.navbar
{
    height:86px;
    margin-bottom:0
}
```

To

```
.navbar
{
    margin-bottom:0
}
```

small: http://jsfiddle.net/KNPZB/7/
big: http://fiddle.jshell.net/KNPZB/7/show/

Comment: hey how did you find it...can you let me know so that I wont repeat it

Comment: It's very easy. On the small screen when you hover the button you had the pointer curser but on the big screen you had the default pointer. Thus a other element was above the button.
right click on the button and "inspect the element"(chrome, safari and firefox) with this tools you can see what element is above the other one.